# When will the application receive a install_referrer with content utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set)?

Tags: android, deeplink, install-referrer

I'm using instll_referrrer tracking the user installation. Recently, I found a lot of user send the refer `utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set)` to my server.

I searched this on Google, and find a artical https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/E54ae9beKLB which tell me this will be set as default for user from deeplinks. And then I searched the definition of deeplink but I don't quite understand it.

> From now on, if there is no referrer parameter in the URL, a default
>   will be set to separate organic installs from deeplinks (i.e. a third
>   party referral to your Play Store listing).

Dose this means if I received some install_referrer with content `content utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set)`,the user who sent these referrer have installed my app by third party referral which has a format like `{scheme}://{host_path}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation states that it only occurs when you use the deeplink (http) to the play store:

> For a deep link into Google Play where the referrer parameter is not
>   present or empty, the referrer value provided is:
>
> ```
> utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set)
> ```

For instance:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps
```

Documentation here: https://developers.google.com/app-conversion-tracking/third-party-trackers/android

Comment: Thanks, but I still do not quite understand the different between organic and deeplink. For example ,if I click the link you posted (It's not an Ad) ```https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps``` , how can Google Play decide to give me 'not set' or 'organic' ?

Comment: Deeplink would be when using your own domain name, otherwise it's when you use the play.google.com domain name.

Comment: unable to understand that why my app is still getting utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set).need help.what should be excat url format so that i do not get  not%20set

Comment: i really cant understand where the given document link is talking about the mentioned issue..please help

Comment: I got the same issue not able to understand the problem.

Comment: Facing the same problem with this link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<ID>&referrer=utm_source%3D<VAL1>%26utm_medium%3D<VAL2>

Comment: @HarishLalwani did you solve this problem? I have it currently :(

Comment: Google play store checks all the mail accounts which are logged into Google play and if you are logged in with work email (enterprise domain email id)it sets the UTM property as utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set).

So try removing work email from google play store and verify.

Use Google Play URL Builder to generate campaign URL.

It's worked for me

Comment: @biki Today, you were my hero! Thank you!

Comment: @Biki this worked for me. I don't see it mentioned anywhere. Where did you find it?

Answer (score 8):

Google play store checks all the mail accounts which are logged into Google play and if you are logged in with work email (enterprise domain email id)it sets the UTM property as utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set).

So try removing work email from google play store and verify.

Use [Google Play URL Builder](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-url-builder) to generate campaign URL.

It's worked for me

Comment: Is this behaviour documented somewhere? Also, is there a proper solution around it? And will the behaviour be the same for real users on production as well?

Answer (score 1):

Your URL needs to have a "referrer" parameter, and encode your referrer in there. An example is

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=a&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dcpc%26anid%3Dadmob
```

You can try to use this https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns to create examples.

Answer (score 0):

The apps do not pass referrer to the store if it comes from Google and Facebook.

So you get `utm_source=(not%20set)&utm_medium=(not%20set)`