# Deferred facebook deeplink don`t pass install-referrer to play store

Tags: android, facebook, broadcastreceiver, install-referrer

I have implemented install-referrer fetching with broadcast receiving with com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER. And it's working great with google play directly, like https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.myapp&referrer=utm_source%3DFacebook%26utm_medium%3DCpc

But, when I try to use it with facebook deferred deeplink, it gives me "not%20set" for all variables. I have tried different looks of deeplink, like "myapp://deep?referrer=utm_source%3DFacebook%26utm_medium%3DCpc" and "myapp://referrer=utm_source%3DFacebook%26utm_medium%3DCpc" but it didn't pass parameters.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting (not%20set) for UTM parameters with Install Referrer- Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707569/getting-not20set-for-utm-parameters-with-install-referrer-android)