# Having no campaign params from google ads app promotion

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-ads-api, utm

I just make one **App campaign**  from google adword.

having an issue regarding user came from ads campaign those having *not set* referrerUrl and wrong UTM params

I have used new install referrer client provided [android library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library)

everything working fine I got a custom UTM params from our website. but only issue that user came **from Ad campaign**

```
com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2
```

**my code as like below**

[image]

I just set **default** organic if it **return not set**

[image]

I don't know what I have missing. but that particular flow not working

*everything working fine* with custom URL and a user came from directly PlayStore. the only problem that the user came from **adcampaign**

Comment: There could be one more possible scenario where you get 'not set' values in referring params when you are logged in through your work email. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65475325/1903338 answer and verify once. Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set up your custom campaigns manually, make sure you separate the parameters from the URL with a question mark. List the parameters and values as pairs separated by an equal sign. Separate each parameter-value pair with an ampersand. For example:

https://www.example.com/?utm_source=email_campaign&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=summer-sale

You can add parameters to a URL in any order. Note that Analytics is case sensitive, so utm_source=google is different from utm_source=Google. Case sensitivity applies for each value you define.

Comment: brother, there is no option  to put custom URL in app campaign in admob.